# Check if cell is selected and format it accordingly iOS UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, selected

I am trying to implement a functionality where I want to set the first row of a UITableView as selected. The UITableView is a subview of my UIViewController . I am able to select the 1st row through my UIViewController. Like so :-

```
  var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0);

 newTableChoice.Source = new RatingScaleSource(this,data.TypeAsString ,data.Title, choiceList);
 newTableChoice.SelectRow(indexPath, false, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top);
```

Now I want to implement it further in my DataSource, where if the first row is selected then I want to add an accessory to it so that the user knows that particular row is selected by default.

I tried implementing this in my RatingScaleSource class which is my DataSource :-

```
  public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
      cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("ChoiceTableCell") as ChoiceTableCell;
        if (tableView.CellAt(indexPath).Selected)
        {
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
        }
    }
```

But this crashes the app as the Cell is not yet created. I want to know which Function can detect if the row is already selected and where I can add the accessory. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use 'CellForRowAtIndexPath' instead of GetCell method.

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman this is Xamarin code. `GetCell` method is equivalent to 'CellForRowAtIndexPath'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SelectRow definition here](http://Calling%20this%20method%20does%20not%20trigger%20UITableViewSource.WillSelectRow(UITableView,NSIndexPath)%20nor%20will%20it%20send%20UITableView.SelectionDidChangeNotification%20notifications.)

We can see the following sentences in `Remarks`

> Calling this method does not trigger UITableViewSource.WillSelectRow(UITableView,NSIndexPath) nor will it send UITableView.SelectionDidChangeNotification notifications.

No method will be triggered with this method.

`tableView.CellAt(indexPath)` at `GetCell` is incorrect, because the cell hasn't returned at that time(means it  is not yet created).

I tried the following code but no luck, I think the tableview selects the row after finishing the render delegate.

```
cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("ChoiceTableCell") as ChoiceTableCell;
if (cell.Selected)
{
     cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
}
```

#### Solution:

So since you have known the index which should be selected, you can set the Accessory with same condition in `GetCell`

```
if (indexPath.IsEqual(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0)))
{
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
}
else
{
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.